# Ballerina json datetime value

Tags: json, datetime, elasticsearch, ballerina

i have to index documents to elasticsearch to an index which has a date field mapping and i'm trying to build a json with this date value, but ballerina says this seems not possible.

- I thought about storing this date value into an xml and after that to convert it to a json but xml has the same problem (i thought this might be a trick...).
- I tried to store it into a string and after that to extract the json payload from that string but it gives me this error:

> error: {ballerina/io}GenericError message=unrecognized token 'date=time=1591128342000'

- I thought about dealing with this string to date conversion from inside elasticsearch but i would like to keep this scenario as the last one. I don't like it, beacause i have to do some queries based on timestamp after and storing date as a string would give me additional problems

So is there any way to trick ballerina in order to achive this json containing a date value ?

-----here is snapshot of the code giving me the error-----
It says:

> incompatible types: expected 'json', found 'ballerina/time:Time'

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON is a text format that is completely language independent (see e.g. [json.org](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)).
[`time:Time`](https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/time/records/Time.html) is a Ballerina language specific type JSON knows nothing about. Because there is no implicit conversion (for a good reason) one have to provide the conversion.

In this case you most likely want to convert `time:Time` to a [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string presentation with [`time:toString`](https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/time/functions.html#toString).

The following code (Ballerina 1.2):

```
import ballerina/io;
import ballerina/time;
public function main() {
    var btime = time:currentTime();
    var j = <json> {
        time: time:toString(btime)
    };

    io:println(j.toJsonString());
}
```

Correctly prints:

```
{"time":"2020-06-03T08:39:07.897+03:00"}
```

Maryam Ziyad has written a good [introduction to Ballerina's JSON support](https://medium.com/ballerina-techblog/ballerinas-json-type-and-lax-static-typing-3b952f6add01).

Comment: Broken link references:
https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/time/latest
https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/time/latest/functions#utcToString

Comment: This is now an outdated answer that reflects the state of the Ballerina 1.2 version in 2020 and answers to the original question. The answer is not applicable to newer Ballerina versions as time related functionality has changed radically.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is updated for Ballerina Swan Lake Update 1 (2201.1.0) to show how to convert a Ballerina UTC time (`time:Utc`) to JSON representation. Note that it's also possible to use localized time (`time:Civil`) but that is no different from time to JSON conversion point of view.

One can read more about Ballerina time handling from the documentation of [`time` module](https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/time/latest).

```
import ballerina/io;
import ballerina/time;
public function main() {
    time:Utc now = time:utcNow(3);

    json j = {
        time: time:utcToString(now)
    };

    io:println(j.toJsonString());
}
```

That correctly prints:

```
{"time":"2022-07-20T06:03:46.078Z"}
```